# Removing arrays whose multidimensional elements don't appear in another array?

Tags: php, arrays, comparison, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array called `$item_list`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [customer] => Joe Bloggs
            [details] => Text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [customer] => Fred Smith
            [details] => Text
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [customer] => John Doe
            [details] => Text
        )
)
```

I have another array from a different database (hence, no SQL solution) called `$id_list` which holds the `$item_list` IDs that I want to *keep*:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 14
)
```

Is there a way I can remove `$item_list[1]` by comparing `$item_list[1]['id']` against the elements in `$id_list` without manually iterating over the `$item_list` arrays using `foreach()` or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$keep = array(12, 14);

$data = array_filter($data, function ($a) use ($keep)
{
  return in_array($a['id'], $keep);
});
```

Note you could `array_flip` the `$keep` first and use `isset()` for a more optimized solution.

Comment: I still don't understand `array_filter()` but your solution works perfectly, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Kalessin, `array_filter` simply iterates over the passed array, calling the specified function for every element. If that function call returns `true` for that element, it is included in the list returned. I'm using an anonymous function for brevity's sake, but you could use a standalone function and reference it by name instead.